# sorting string values in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

I have a dictionary:

```
data = {
    'Description': 'test',
    'Amount': '100000',
    'TerminalKey': '1508852342226',
    'OrderId': 'TokenExample',
    'Password': '123456'
}
```

and I need to get a single string of sorted values:

```
'100000testTokenExample1234561508852342226'
```

My code:

```
data = "".join([v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(1))])
```

outputs this:

```
'1000001234561508852342226TokenExampletest'
```

Can someone explain why I’m getting a different value and how I can get the one I need?

Comment: `''.join(sorted(d.values()))` is the shorter way to get your output. As far as your question goes, *why* did you expect something else?

Comment: Why would you expect `test` to sort before `1508852342226`?

Comment: `itemgetter(1)` returns value, `itemgetter(0)` returns key. Use `itemgetter(0)` if you want to sort by keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to sort the *keys*, and then join the corresponding *values*. Please give this a try:

```
data = {
 'Description': 'test',
 'Amount': '100000',
 'TerminalKey': '508852342226',
 'OrderId': 'TokenExample',
 'Password': '123456',
}

''.join(data[k] for k in sorted(data))
=> '100000testTokenExample123456508852342226'
```

Of course, your solution also works (it's a bit longer, though). You just have to use `itemgetter(0)` as the sorting key, that'll be the dict's *key*:

```
''.join(v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(0)))
=> '100000testTokenExample123456508852342226'
```

Even simpler: we don't even need to explicitly specify the sorting key, by default the ordering of tuples will do exactly what you want:

```
''.join(v for k, v in sorted(data.items()))
=> '100000testTokenExample123456508852342226'
```

Comment: Yeah it works, thanks a lot. Can you explain the difference in advance? I’d be glad to understand this

Comment: Your solution also works, as long as you replace the last part with `itemgetter(0)`. You need to sort on the _keys_, not on the values.

Answer (score 3):

That's because with a `key=itemgetter(1)` you are sorting *by value*.

To sort by key, like you are requesting with your example, use `itemgetter(0)`:

```
>>> "".join([v for k, v in sorted(data.items(), key=itemgetter(0))])
'100000testTokenExample1234561508852342226'
```

Note that also simply sorting the item tuples (using their natural ordering), you get the same sorting:

```
>>> "".join([v for k, v in sorted(data.items())])
'100000testTokenExample1234561508852342226'
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want to sort the keys of `d` and then concatenate the corresponding values.

```
>>> ''.join(v for k, v in sorted(data.items()))
'100000testTokenExample1234561508852342226'
```

This is similar to Óscar's answer, but I prefer not to explicitly 'index' into the dict.